# Create table in sharepoint excel file using REST API?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a table given a range of cells in a Sharepoint Excel file.

For this purpose I'm consulting Microsoft Graph REST API documentation in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0)

However, when I try to create the table, I see that the request for "Create table" is a bit weird as it does not specify the worksheet nor the range from which I want to create the table...

Any ideas how to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablecollection-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the request body has property `address` where the range and optional sheet name is specified.

Endpoints:

```
POST /me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/tables/add
POST /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/workbook/tables/add
POST /me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/tables/add
POST /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/tables/add
```

Request body:

```
{
  "address": "Sheet1!A1:D5",
  "hasHeaders": true
}
```

The [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0#create-table) you are referencing is really weird and probably wrong (endpoint `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}/workbook/tables/{table-id}/add` is wrong. You don't know the table id before creation and the request body is also wrong).

Resources:

[Create table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablecollection-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example)